# Latex Tikzpictures multiple entries

Tags: latex

I've got a problem with tikzpicture. I've made my cv in Latex but one thing isn't working fine. In a skill graph I got multiple entries. Here's the code.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}

\begin{tikzpicture}[thick,scale=0.8, every node/.style={scale=0.8},every node/.style={font=\sffamily}]
\begin{axis}[title  = \textbf{Sprachen},
xbar,
y axis line style = { opacity = 0 },
axis x line       = none,
tickwidth         = 0pt,
%enlarge y limits={abs=1cm},
enlarge x limits  = 0.02,
symbolic y coords = { Französisch, Englisch, Deutsch},
%nodes near coords,
xmin=0,
xmax=1,
]
\addplot coordinates { 
    (1,Deutsch)
    (0.65,Englisch)
    (0.3,Französisch)
};

%\legend{Topics}
\end{axis}
\node[text width=3cm] at (1.5,-0.5) 
{Grundkennt.};
\node[text width=3cm] at (5.25,-0.5) 
{gut};
\node[text width=3cm] at (7.4,-0.5) 
{sehr gut};
\draw (2.5,0.1) -- (2.5, 5.5);
\draw (5,0.1) -- (5, 5.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[Multiple entries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mpX51.png)

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hua1o.png)
 I hope one of you could help me.

Greetz Michi

Comment: This should instead be asked at the dedicated stack exchange site for LaTeX questions: http://tex.stackexchange.com

Comment: Okay, i'll do that tomorrow. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

uncomment the

```
enlarge y limits={abs=1cm},
```

and it should work, or do you want to have different distances? Then try this code:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[thick,every node/.style={font=\sffamily}]
\begin{axis}[ title=\textbf{Sprachen},
xbar, 
width=12cm, height=3.5cm, enlarge y limits=0.5, 
y axis line style = { opacity = 0 },
axis x line       = none,
tickwidth         = 0pt,
%xlabel={\#participants}, 
symbolic y coords={Französisch, Englisch, Deutsch},
ytick=data, 
%nodes near coords, 
nodes near coords align={horizontal}, ] 
\addplot coordinates {(1,Deutsch) (0.65,Englisch) (0.3,Französisch)}; 
\end{axis}  
    \node[text width=3cm] at (1.5,-0.5) 
    {Grundkennt.};
    \node[text width=3cm] at (5.25,-0.5) 
    {gut};
    \node[text width=3cm] at (7.4,-0.5) 
    {sehr gut};
    \draw (2.5,0.1) -- (2.5, 1.95);
    \draw (5,0.1) -- (5, 1.95);

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I had to recode it and use an example from [this page](http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/gallery.html) as template. I still don't know what caused this repeated language labels. But this solution should solve it and have decreased distances.

By the way, if you are looking for a good template for CV's in LaTeX look on Overleaf (I like moderncv).

Comment: You're right that works, but there is still a little problem. The distance is to heavy in my opinion. I add an example pic take a look on it. The first graphic schould be equal to the other ones. Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: what if you do not take absolute values in the y limits? Will play with it in my lunch break

Comment: I've tried that but then the entries will be appear twice. This is a strange behavior. Thank you in advance that you spend your time with this problem.

Comment: Don't know if you got an answer in the tex commnity. But I updated my take on it

Comment: Cool! Thanl you very much!